# Как создать текстовый шаблон (например Word) в который бы передавались данные

Tags: php, post, get, text, ms-word

Нужно решение благодаря которому данные принимались по url/GET/POST, генерировался Вордовский или другой текстовый файл (по заданному шаблону, куда бы передаваемые данные подставлялись бы) и отправлялся клиенту, то есть файл скачивался на компьютер.
Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь подобные сервисы или готовые решения (на php,java) ?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/119551/ как вариант. Или так https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater

Answer (score 0):

Можно это все в php сделать

```
$Word = $this->load->view('/view_word_shablon', $this->data, true);          

$Word = "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $Word; // UTF-8 BOM 

$filename = 'export-word-' . $id . '.doc';

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: application/msword");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . ";");
header("Content-Length: " . $filename);

$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($filename, $Word);
```

Это рабочий код, сделан на CodeIgniter. Шаблон содержит простой php файл с несколькими `echo` и `print` и др.

Может поможет.

Comment: а не могли бы помочь объяснить, куда мне вставить шаблон вордовского док-а. Вот например я хочу отправить данные POST запросом в php. И далее php принимает данные, подставляет их в заранее заготовленный шаблон .doc (или .rtf) и возвращает клиенту на скачивание

Comment: @illusion Вы какой фреймвок используете? или чистом php все делаете?

Comment: чистый php, собственно база данных сделана на конструкторе Zoho, из бд данные можно отправить, например POSTóm, и чтобы клиенту уже вернулся готовый .rtf .doc где данные были подставлены в шаблон